# Amazon Managed Airflow Dags wont sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

Did anyone try the new Amazon managed services Airflow? I did all the steps mentioned and could open airflow link. But none of the dags are synched. I don't see any error. I event tried updating the environment with a different S3 bucket .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading dags in the dags folder in your **s3** bucket?

`dags.py` should be inside the dags folder in **s3** bucket to get synced.